# Using variables in get() in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I want to write multiple tests for the sign-up flow in my web app. This means filling out a form with the same values multiple times, like this:

```
 cy.get('[name="password1"]').type('qqqqqq')
```

To make my tests easier to maintain, I want to use a variable instead of "password1" so that I only have to change in one place if the name of the form field changes. In other words, I want something like this

```
cy.get('[name=MY_PASSWORD]').type('qqqqqq')
```

where MY_PASSWORD is set in the test file or in the configuration file.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [custom commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html) to achieve this. Go to `cypress/support/commands.js` and write:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('inputPassword', (myPassword) => {
  cy.get("[name=" + `"` + myPassword + `"` + "]").type('qqqqqq')
})
```

In your test you can write:

```
cy.inputPassword(password1)
```

Comment: Just realized I could do like this: cy.get(Cypress.env('signup_password1')).type('qqqqqq') and specify the variable signup_password1 in the configuration file. Your solution could be even more elegant, thanks!